# Specifying swift version in coremltools conversion

Tags: ios, swift, keras, coreml, coremltools

Is it possible to specify the swift version that coremltools writes the mlmodel in? I have macOS 10.14 beta installed, and am trying to load a coreml model to iOS 11.x, which does not support swift 4.2. When I load the model into Xcode, i get an error:

```
Error generating model class : unrecognized Swift version "4.2". Expected one of: 3.0, 3.1, 3.2 or 4.0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you are currently using a swift version >4.0.
You can use the Toolchains feature in Xcode to use a SWIFT 4.0 version.

To do so, download it here https://swift.org/download/#releases and install it.

Check this if you need help to install the version https://m.pardel.net/using-old-versions-of-swift-in-xcode-4dd46644a257

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I understand how to switch toolchains from the Xcode app, but what about the command line? To complicate things further, I am running both Xcode 9.4 and Xcode-beta. It seems that the swift version used by command line calls to python/coremltools use the versions given in the Xcode-beta.

Comment: I figured it out, used your link to find a solution here: https://medium.com/xcblog/switching-swift-versions-inside-xcode-using-toolchains-755b28831c43